# What does a NULL no-op compile to on GCC/Clang?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gcc, clang, llvm

I have several debugging functions throughout my code, and when the build flag -release is specified the calls are all replaced with NULL (for performance); for example:

```
self.condition ? NULL : NULL;
```

where the first and second NULLs were function calls that got replaced in preprocessing.

My question is what does this compile to, if anything?  I'm using Apple's LLVM 5.1; obviously to us it's a no-op so does that mean it generates no instructions from this line?  I would hope it's that way, since there's no good reason to actually execute anything.

Comment: Check the disassembly, it's the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that it would depend on context.

Since `self.condition` is an alias for `[self condition]` that call can only be omitted if the compiler can positively assert that `[self condition]` has no side effects.  If the compiler cannot establish there are no side effects, then the entire statement can be optimized to `[self condition];` yielding a slight optimization.

`_condition ? NULL : NULL;` should be safely dead stripped since there is no associated method call with possible side effects.

Comment: Excellent; you're right about the call so I've put __attribute__ ((pure)) on my conditional methods